# ADFS + Google: login credentials could not be verified

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, g-suite, adfs

We migrated to the G-Suite Gmail last year, everything was working normally. AD FS page is runnign on windows server 2k12. Since yesterday google could not validate credentials => AD FS page login successfully, but google g-suit print error: `Login credentials could not be verified`

Yesteday we upload to the win server image of win10 (to WDS) and we recently update php fpm to 7.1 on the other web server.